# Custom Infinite-post-scrolling in a custom theme:

Tags: theme-development

In the process of attempting to implement "Infinite-Scrolling" in a custom wordpress theme..

I am not using the jetpack plugin, I followed this tutorial (http://wptheming.com/2012/03/infinite-scroll-to-wordpress-theme/) but have had absolutely no luck. It seems as if the JS isnt even loading even though its in the proper location.

site: http://www.gd-gaming.com/wordpress

Code being used: (This is all in functions.php)

```
        /**
 * Load javascripts used by the theme
 */

function custom_theme_js(){
    wp_register_script( 'infinite_scroll',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js', array('jquery'),null,true );
    if( ! is_singular() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('infinite_scroll');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_js');

/**
 * Infinite Scroll
 */
function custom_infinite_scroll_js() {
    if( ! is_single() ) { ?>
    <script>
    var infinite_scroll = {
        loading: {
            img: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif",
            msgText: "<?php _e( 'Loading the next set of posts...', 'custom' ); ?>",
            finishedMsg: "<?php _e( 'All posts loaded.', 'custom' ); ?>"
        },
        "nextSelector":".nav-previous .alignleft",
        "navSelector":".nav-previous",
        "itemSelector":"#container .box",
        "contentSelector":"#container"
    };
    jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_infinite_scroll_js',100 );
```

Comment: Ok, I've added the debugging, heres what it came with: Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Line 2959.... Whats weird is, I placed everything relating to infinite-scrolling at the top of functions.php

Comment: Also, not showing any errors in the error console. I also enabled Script Debug through wp-config and that didnt help.

Comment: It could be that another function hooked to wp_enqueue_scripts is causing the problem. Which file is is referring to line 2959 of? Try removing each of your two functions, one at a time, to make sure it real is the infinite scroll functions, and if so, which one, that is causing the error.

Comment: I just delved a little deeper into the debugger and found this, [00:09:03.448] TypeError: jQuery(...).infinitescroll is not a function. EDIT: The file its referring to is functions.php, how can I find the line the error is showing up on?

Comment: Your debugger should tell you which line of function.php it is looking for. Hard to know what's up until you do some troubleshooting, like removing the functions as I described above. Also try moving infinite scroll itself to the header by setting the last argument in wp_enqueue_script to false.

Comment: Alright, the source of the "Line 2959" error was not related to the infinite scrolling. How can I set the argument to false? Ill try that next.. I'd also like to throw out there that I really appreciate the help, Im extremely thankful for this.

Comment: Replace the second line with `wp_register_script( 'infinite_scroll',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js', array('jquery'),null,false );` note I changed the last arg to false, which makes WordPress not add infinitescroll.min.js in the footer. BTW- Thank you. You can thank me even more with upvotes on my comments:) BTW2- You can see how I implemented this tutorial starting on line 75 of https://github.com/Shelob9/_sf_lib/blob/master/scripts-styles.php

Comment: No luck with that either, Hmm, Should I try following your tutorial? Should be a nice easy switch out of selectors and file paths... Also, I dont have an option to upvote your comments?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm not a complete and utter dumbass, Could you look at my site with a development tool and see if this is as simple as incorrect selectors?

Comment: Sure what's the url? I could use a break from feeling like a dumbass myself. The upvote icon should appear when you hover over the comment.

Comment: http://www.gd-gaming.com/wordpress I dont get the icon =/ Possibly because of my lack of rep, I'm not sure.

Comment: If you look at your page source you will see that the infinite scroll plugin isn't added to the page. Also you should keep in mind that adding infinite scroll to masonry, which btw isn't working either, is tricky.

Comment: My best guess on selectors BTW is "`nextSelector":".nav-previous a","navSelector":".nav-previous", "itemSelector":".box", "contentSelector":"#container"` but you've got to get that plugin in there first. Did you change the wp_register_script function yet?

Comment: Very interesting, Masonry is working in all 3 browsers for me. But yes, I did try changing the script function and had no luck.

Comment: Masonry doesn't seem to do anything for me. I'm using Chrome in OSX 10.6.8. My javascript console is showing errors on your page related to something called Spry, which it can't load. Try removing whatever that is.

Comment: Wtf could be causing it to work for me and not you? Spry has been removed..... Is there any script I need to put in the header for Infinite Scrolling to work? Also works on my iphone with chrome and safari

Comment: Try adding a really low priority to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action like this `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_js', 3);` BTW You do have WP_DEBUG set to true right?

Comment: Interesting, I just read on another post the infinite scrolling is broke in jquery 1.9.1, Could this be my issue?

Comment: No I didnt have it on, Just turned it back on and I was given an error that my masonry script was en queued incorrectly. Removed it and there are no more errors. Added in the new action, not seeing any improvement.

Comment: You are using jQuery 1.8.3 so don't worry about that. Though you've now got me worrying about that future issue. Anyway try removing the function that enqueues Masonry and then replace the first function for infinite scroll with this: http://pastebin.com/dK0LA1ai

Comment: Done, Masonry is working again, Infinite Annoyingness however, is not. I'd really like to give some damn upvotes, wish this would allow me to... Let me go over some things quick. For whatever reason, the script doesnt seem to be loading... That could be a file path issue.. or a direct file issue. The file path is correct and I'm confident the file is fine.

Comment: If it were a file path issue, you would see a 404 error in your console. Try it without the !is_singluar conditional like this: http://pastebin.com/BuGLsMFS . BTW I'm off to bed for the night, sorry I couldn't figure this out, but I hope I got you on the fit track. Be sure to check your page source to see if the infinite scroll plugin is being added. Also, as an experiment, try hardcoding the links to the plugin into the header.php, which is a terrible long-term solution, but a good troubleshooting step.

Comment: Well, its definitely an issue with my custom theme. I've tried using the two plugins and doing it custom. I just switched over to Twenty Twelve and enabled "jetpack" and it worked without any problems.